# How to access google analytics data without username/password

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I have a database with some google analytics data from our clients. I have three values:
AuthKeyId, ProfileId and AnalyticsID. How can I use this data to get the data from google?

Here's the code I tried but I'm getting unauthorized error message:

```
    string authToken = "XXxXXxxx_XXX_xxxx...."; // this seems to be wrong

    string feed = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";

    string ids = "ga:XXXXXXX";       // this is the ID, the correct one
    string metrics = "ga:pageviews";
    string startDate = "2013-06-25";
    string endDate = "2013-07-25";

    //Optional:
    string sort = "-ga:pageviews";

    string feedUrl = string.Format("{0}?ids={1}&dimensions={2}&metrics={3}&sort={4}&start-date={5}&end-date={6}",
        feed, ids, dimensions, metrics, sort, startDate, endDate);

    webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin " + authToken);
    string result = webClient.DownloadString(feedUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google analytics auth tokens do not last forever. The have to be renewed. If what you have there is a refresh token, they don't expire unless the user that granted permission revokes access.

The best way to go is with a service account as @Petr is suggested.

There are a few more steps to creating the service account and generating the `.p12` file you will need. You can follow the directions for setting up a service account here: [Connecting to Google Analytics API in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120772/connecting-to-google-analytics-api-in-a-rails-app/21128605#21128605)

Google's code examples seem to be lacking in the `c#` arena but I did find this post:
[How do I use a Service Account to Access the Google Analytics API V3 with .NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980215/how-do-i-use-a-service-account-to-access-the-google-analytics-api-v3-with-net-c)

Answer (score 0):

Create a project in [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), which Google actually requires (also noted in the [GA docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide#before)):

1. Register your application in the Google Developers Console.
2. Authorize access to Google Analytics data.
3. Create an Analytics service object.

Hope this helps!